# Wordpress Ajax - Always returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

console.log(data) always returns 0, I have looked through other answers and they all say either add die(); or add action wp_ajax_nopriv... which I've already done. Can anybody else help me find a solution?

Javascript:

```
$('#formID').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
    var data = {
        action: 'testFunction',
    }

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Functions.php function

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_testFunction', 'testFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_testFunction', 'testFunction' );
function testFunction()
{
    echo "test";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hook is wrong.

Your have to do this :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_testFunction', 'testFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_testFunction', 'testFunction' );
function testFunction()
{
    echo "test";
    die();
}
```

Remove the "add" in your hook.

I hope that help you.

ps: check the codex at section "example" (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Comment: Thank you very much! I took the add_actions from the WP codex but obviously messed up modifying it for use with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont get the die(), your function might not be called...
You should look in the panel 'network' of a developper tool as firebug to see your request and the response... and maybe an error.

else it may be a wordpress thing, then you should ask this question on a wordpress specialized forum.